# What should be the JVM heap size (Xms Xmx) for JDK8 64-bit on Linux having physical memory of 16 GB RAM and 8 CPU

Tags: java, jvm, 64-bit, heap-memory, permgen

I have 16GB of RAM and 8 CPU's on my Linux server with JDK8 x64 installed.

I have set up JVM heap size as below but keep getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

Any suggestions, what should be the minimum/maximum/PermGen heap size.

Comment: That absolutely depends on the application you are running. Can you please give us some more insights on that?

Comment: *keep getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError* More than you have

Comment: BTW. If you are running a Java 8 application you can get rid of `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`. This is no longer supported by Java8 ( The memory model used for loaded classes and methods is different and isn't limited (with default settings))

Comment: If you don't have a clue what is going on try to generate a heap dump: `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. Than you can see what consumes all the memory.

Comment: Can you please show us the entire stack-trace?

Comment: Not all OOME have the same cause. It can mean perm or meta space is too small or you have run out if resources for threads. It could mean your heap is too small or too large. You need to say what is the message which comes with it.

Comment: @TobiSH - I can see below error in tomcat catalina.out logs - 

Exception in thread "http-bio-10.20.5.140-8080-exec-20" Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)"

Comment: @PeterLawrey we can preclude permgen issues for a Java 8 installation.

Answer (score 3):

Out of memory error is caused, because the heap size consumed by your code is more than what is allocated by Java.

This could be because of multiple reasons.

1) **Your code is bulky and needs more memory**: A simple code to just print "Hello World" won't consume much memory. However, a lengthy and bulky application of 1 GB source code would consume huge memory. If that is case, you can try to increase your memory arguments.

2) **Bad Code**: Bad code, which consumes useless memory, and does not release it later, causes more heap size to be used continously than the garbage collected. If that is the code you might need to identify the issue with your code. You can actually identify the method or class that is consuming this huge amount of heap, using [Java Flight Record (JFR)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328).

Ideal Heap Memory Size varies from from case to case and your requirements must be known for exact heap size.